# Where does IE store the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2005, internet-explorer-7, session-cookies

I am a bit baffled here; using IE7, ASP.NET 2.0 and Cassini (the VS built-in web server; although the same thing seems to be true for "real" applications deployed in IIS) I am looking for the session-id-cookie.

My test page shows a session id (by printing out `Session.SessionId`) and `Response.Cookies.Keys` contains `ASP.NET_SessionId`. So far so good.

But **I cannot find the cookie in IEs cookie-store!** Nor does "remove all cookies" reset the session (as it does in FF)... So where - I am tempted to write that four letter word - does IE store that bloody cookie? Or am I missing something? By the way there is no hidden field with a session id either, as far as I can see.

If I check in FF there is a cookie called `ASP.NET_SessionId` as I would expect. And as mentioned above deleting that cookie does start a new session; as I would expect.

Can anybody imagine what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET session cookie is non-persistent, so it doesn't get saved to your hard-drive.  It gets transmitted back and forth while you're using the application, but it gets discarded when you close the broswer.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx):

> Note
>
> When you run this code, you might see
>   a cookie named ASP.NET_SessionId. That
>   is a cookie that ASP.NET uses to store
>   a unique identifier for your session.
>   The session cookie is not persisted on
>   your hard disk. For more about session
>   cookies, see the "Cookies and Session
>   State" later in this topic.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes... I did read that note as well but obviously did not understand what it meant at that time :( Still I do not understand why IE thinks it could possibly be desired that it keeps sending some cookies after the user explicitly purged all cookies... But that is - well - IE.